# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

Hi I am trying to add an icon to my button, it seems it works fine for one image but as soon as i change the image to some other image  i get this error: the only difference is that the previous image had a resolution of 48x48 and the new image has a resolution of 32x32

Here is the code:

```
dashboardButton = new JButton("Dashboard", new ImageIcon("images/dashbd.png"));
        dashboardButton.addActionListener(this);
        topPanel.add(dashboardButton, topCC.xy(2,2));
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1016)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:338)
    at in.tcs.dct.ui.custom.UnifiedToolbarButtonUI.paintIcon(UnifiedToolbarButtonUI.java:48)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.paint(BasicButtonUI.java:216)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:793)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1072)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:871)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:797)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:759)
    at in.tcs.dct.ui.DCTFrame.windowClosing(DCTFrame.java:146)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(AWTEventMulticaster.java:349)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2045)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:296)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2003)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ..as soon as i change the image to some other image i get this error: the only difference is that the previous image had a resolution of 48x48 and the new image has a resolution of 32x32

So you are saying this code fails for you?  It works just fine here.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangingIconResolution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final BufferedImage img32 = new BufferedImage(
                32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        final BufferedImage img48 = new BufferedImage(
                48, 48, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JButton btn = new JButton(new ImageIcon(img48));
                ActionListener animationAction = new ActionListener() {
                    int index = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (index++%3==0) {
                            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img32));
                        } else {
                            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img48));
                        }
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, animationAction);
                timer.start();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, btn);
                timer.stop();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the image. I had actually created an icon from the image using an online editor that gave me an *.ico file, which I had converted to *.png. Hence got the error. When I used another image editor that gave me an output image in *.jpg/*.png format it worked. And also check your the path is correct. I got an error when I set the icon to a Frame (Task bar). So check that your image's path is correct.

So you are saying this code fails for you? It works just fine here. -  said "Andrew Thompson"

So it is a error in path.

Comment: *"guess there was an issue with the image.."* Nothing like a little testing to check the veracity of a claim.  ;)